# How to count things from different tables and group it by user?

Tags: group-by, count, sum, union

I have those 3 tables
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10wBb.png)
and i don't know how to connect them to have a users.id, username, number of likes and number of comments by each user. I want to have it in 4 columns.

I tried this:
select u.id, u.username, count(l.photo_id) as posts_liked from users u left join likes l on u.id = l.user_id group by u.id
UNION ALL
select u.id, u.username, count(c.user_id) as com_written from users u left join comments c on u.id = c.user_id group by u.id;
but the result is just 3 tables with number of comments in a column with number of likes.

Answer (score 0):

I join the three tables and then grouped by id. Try this if it answer your question

```
SELECT 
    u.id, 
    u.username, 
    count(l.photo_id) as nro_likes,
    count(c.photo_id) as nro_comments
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN comments c
ON u.id = c.id
INNER JOIN likes l
ON c.user_id = l.user_id
GROUP BY u.id
```

Comment: I have already tried this and it's wrong. It shows the same number of likes and the same number of comments.

Comment: can you show the tables to help you and the desire output? I just use an example for that